# Loopback - redirect all traffic to index.html

Tags: express, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm building a `react` single page application using for backend, `loopback`.

**How can I set, in the middleware, all the traffic (except API calls to the server and asset files like css, js,...) to go to `index.html`?**

Here is what I have for the moment in my `middleware.json` configuration for the files page.:

```
"files": {
        "loopback#static": [
            {
                "paths": [
                    "/storage"
                ],
                "params": "$!../storage"
            },

            {
                "paths": [
                    "/*"
                ],
                "params": "$!../client/index.html"
            },
            {
                "paths": [
                    "/*.*"
                ],
                "params": "$!../client"
            }
        ]
    },
```

At the moment, it seems like all traffic is indeed redirected to `index.html` but so are the css, js, ...

Any ideas?